# Missing Order.Lattice function from Arend standard library added by Intellij IDEA plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, proof

I tried to prove some lemmas about Implicative Lattice and decided to use function `meet-monotone` from `Order.Lattice.MeetSemilattice`. I found this function in manually downloaded standard lib, but when I'm trying to use it in my code the syntax checker says that there's no such a function.

**Code:**

```
\import Order.LinearOrder
\import Order.PartialOrder
\import Order.Lattice
\import Paths

\open MeetSemilattice

...
    
meet-monotone <=-reflexive join-left
```

**Error:** [ERROR] t1.ard:27:14: Cannot resolve reference 'meet-monotone'

I checked Intellij IDEA plugin lib and there's truly no such a function. At the same time, there's one from manually downloaded lib from Arend website. I use 2021.1 Intellij IDEA Ultimate and my project generated by the plugin has `langVersion: 1.6.0.1` in arend.yaml.